# Get all unique JSON key names with JQ

Tags: json, jq

Is there a way to get all unique key names, without invoking a unique sort outside `jq`?

Example file:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
{"a": 4, "b": 5, "d": 6}
```

And `jq` and sort command as I use it now, but I think it's not so efficient:

```
jq -r keys[] example | sort -u                                                                               
a                                                                                                                                       
b                                                                                                                                       
c                                                                                                                                       
d
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Of course.

```
$ jq -n '[inputs | keys[]] | unique | sort' input.json
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d"
]
```

Here's another option that may perform better as it doesn't require collecting the keys into an array.

```
$ jq -n 'reduce (inputs | keys[]) as $k ({}; .[$k] = null) | keys' input.json
```

Or perhaps, even better:

```
$ jq -n 'foreach (inputs | keys[]) as $k ({}; .[$k]+=1; if .[$k]==1 then $k else empty end)' input.json
```

And for larger files, you will want to stream them in anyway so use this variation:

```
$ jq --stream -n 'foreach inputs[0][-1] as $k ({}; .[$k]+=1; if .[$k]==1 then $k else empty end)' input.json
```

Comment: Thanks! I hoped it would be more memory efficient than my solution, however with a larger file it crashes:

    $ ls -ahgo input.json  
    -rwx------ 1 187M Apr 24 17:40 input.json
    $ jq -r 'keys[]' input.json | sort -u > fields
    $ jq -s 'map(keys) | add | unique' input.json > fields2
    error: cannot allocate memory

Comment: I added a couple more options for this for larger files. If you're still looking for improvements, give these a shot.

Answer (score 6):

Two points:

1. The original solution invoking jq and then sort is efficient, especially  with respect to memory usage.  (The solution involving the -s option effectively forces the entire file to be read into memory).
2. jq's `unique` implies `sort`.  That is, `unique|sort` should be simplified to `unique` to avoid sorting twice.