# Get unique JSON keys with JQ in raw format

Tags: json, jq

This is a follow up question on answer to this question:  [Get all unique JSON key names with JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822622/get-all-unique-json-key-names-with-jq)

How to get the unique keys in raw format from this

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
{"a": 4, "b": 5, "d": 6}
```

The answer to above question is as follows. But this outputs the data in a 'list' like format:

```
$ jq -n '[inputs | keys[]] | unique' input.json
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d"
]
```

How to get just the raw values i.e., a,b,c without open close brackets and double quotes? Usually this can be achieved with `jq -r` but not in this case.

```
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just un-wrap the list generated form unique operation using `unique[]` and still use the raw output mode `-r`

```
jq -nr '[inputs | keys_unsorted[]] | unique[]'
```

I've also used `keys_unsorted` over `keys` to preserve the key ordering.

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hs33CTzHDV)