# jq - reduce array of paths using subpaths

Tags: jq

Assume the following JSON data:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "path": "other/foo/1.15.1",
      "modified": "2022-02-09T13:45:34.638Z"
    },
    {
      "path": "other/foo/1.15.0",
      "modified": "2022-02-09T10:00:40.681Z"
    },
    {
      "path": "a/b/foo/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT",
      "modified": "2022-03-04T19:07:30.262Z"
    },
    {
      "path": "a/b/c/0.1.1",
      "modified": "2022-01-10T15:12:00.597Z"
    },
    {
      "path": "a/b/c/0.1.0",
      "modified": "2022-01-07T18:05:23.158Z"
    },
    {
      "path": "a/b/c/0.0.9",
      "modified": "2021-12-06T10:29:31.161Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

And also assume, that it is descendingly sorted first per `path` then per `modified`.

Now, for every path without its last part, I would like to find only the latest ones according to the `modified` field (which are always on the top because of the sorting). Then, output that path including its last part again.

In other words, for this example data the output should be:

```
other/foo/1.15.1
a/b/foo/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
a/b/c/0.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the common path to a new field, group the objects by the new field, and select the one with the maximal `modified` field.

```
jq -r '[.results[]
          | .short = .path[0:(.path | rindex("/"))]
       ]
       | group_by(.short)[]
       | max_by(.modified).path
      ' file.json
```

Comment: Wow :) Thanks, I can learn a lot from this answer! And I think it's more elegant than using a loop and a regular expression. Also, it doesn't rely on the data to be sorted. Do you have an idea how it performs on large amounts of data?

Comment: No idea about performance. But it shouldn't be too difficult to mock a large input file and benchmark it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using `foreach` and regular expressions, based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829035/1851290

```
jq -n -r 'foreach (inputs | .results| .[]) as $k (
             {};

             .[$k.path | sub("/[^/]*$"; "")]+=1;

             if .[$k.path | sub("/[^/]*$"; "")]==1 then
                 $k.path
             else
                 empty
             end
         )'
```